# View appears with modal view animation instead of show (push) animation

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I've recently updated my app from iOS 8.3 to iOS 9.
After fixing the various errors with the code, I managed to compile the app and run it, when I noticed the following problem.

When I perform a segue clicking, for example, an UIButton, the view loaded with the segue appear with the animation of a modal view (sliding from bottom until it reaches top), but in the storyboard the segue is `Show (e.g. Push)`. In addition, the back button from the navigation controller doesn't appear anymore.

The console print this when I perform a segue:

> `Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UISearchController: 0x7ffde14866b0>)`

The problem seems to be present only in a view, when loading other views, I tried to set other views as Initial View Controller and all works.

Comment: Please post the code that gets called to present the new view controller with the unexpected animation.

Comment: @ndmeiri actually there's no code: I used the storyboard to do a segue.

Comment: Are both of your view controllers in the same Storyboard? And did you make sure that the Initial View Controller in that Storyboard is set to the UINavigationController?

Comment: Yes, they are, and the NavigationController is now set to Initial View Controller, but things don't change. If remove the Navigation Controllers before the views everything seems to work right.

Comment: Hmm, is there anyway for me to take a look at your project? It's difficult to debug without seeing it.

Comment: @ndmeiri sure, it's on github: https://github.com/QUB3X/Hearthdeck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81304/discussion-between-qubex-and-ndmeiri).

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Removing the spare navigation controllers as suggested below resolves the issue, but it seems like more of a work around than an solution, persay. There are a number of people on the Apple developer forums suggesting it may be a bug. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/4201

Answer (score 15, accepted):

After taking a look at the Storyboard in the project, I discovered that the problem was due to extra navigation controllers after each Push segue. That is, in addition to the initial (root) navigation controller, the Storyboard contained a `UINavigationController` as the destination for the problematic Push segues. Removing these extra navigation controllers (but keeping the root navigation controller) solved the problem.

Comment: I've come across the same console error message, but note the following: segues to navigation controllers must remain due to their use with a split view controller (to the detail view controller); (and as a result) code does not require unwind segues (also code includes blocks for setting values in parent view); and the console error message was suppressed by using following line of code in `viewDidLoad`... `[self.searchController loadViewIfNeeded];` (note available from iOS 9).