# Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating... UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have code that creates a `UISearchController' in my UIVIew's`viewDidLoad`.

```
 self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.searchBar.delegate = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false //prevent search bar from moving
        controller.searchBar.placeholder = "Search for song"

        self.myTableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller

    })()
```

Right after this closure finishes, this warning appears in the console:

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UISearchController: 0x154d39700>)
```

I don't get what I am doing wrong. [This similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31830302/why-attempting-to-load-while-deallocating-uisearchcontroller) is not really my situation (At least I don't think so). What is going on?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/583/ Works ok if I throw that into my Table VC `viewDidLoad()`. Recommend a) including entire VC source listing and b) ensuring that the error is really happening where and when you think it is.

Comment: Also, do more research such as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006045/view-appear-with-modal-view-animation-instead-of-show-push-animation which has the same error

Comment: So, I made a swift project, did everything progrmatically, no storyboards, and I have no problem, is this a storyboard's issue you are having, perhaps, I don't know, but I assume you are using storyboards, right? When I say programmatically, I mean no nibs, no storyboards, all code and it works fine

Comment: @BaseZen I set a breakpoint before `})()` and after `})()`. The error gets thrown after the closure ends. I have a `UIViewController`, not a `tableViewController`.

Comment: @Larcerax I do have one storyboard. It contains only a Navigation Controller and a UIViewController (they are connected.)

Comment: Just a note: there is no reason at all to use a closure here.

Answer (score 120):

UISearchController's view has to be removed from its superview before deallocate. (guess it is a bug)

Objective-C...

```
-(void)dealloc { 
    [searchController.view removeFromSuperview]; // It works!
}
```

Swift 3...

```
deinit {
    self.searchController.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I struggled with this issue for a couple of weeks. ^^

Comment: This is really weird... But it did the trick for me too. I guess it is a bug indeed.

Comment: I had the same problem with a `UISearchControler` I was allocating in `-viewDidLoad`. It's definitely a bug - if the `UISearchController` is deallocated before its view is loaded, this warning will appear. If I tap into the search field (thereby loading the view), it does not appear.

So in my `dealloc`, I call `[self.searchController loadViewIfNeeded]` (new in iOS 9),

Comment: @Leehro's comment is the answer for me. it came out as `if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            self.searchController?.loadViewIfNeeded()
        }`

Comment: I'd add to @Leehro's comment that there's no need to do this in dealloc, you can do the loadViewIfNeeded in viewDidLoad instead.

Comment: Thanks to @Leehro and @Clafou... adding the call `[self.searchController loadViewIfNeeded];` (Obj-C) is the answer that solved the problem in my code.

Comment: Thanks @Leehro, this helped me out.

Comment: It is weird, that forcing to remove the view from its superview - I've tried to ask the search controller with 'if ([searchController isViewLoaded])' which returned always nil in dealloc. So forcing to remove it from superview did the trick. I think it must be a bug - they are still not capable to add a UISearchController with IB, even not with Xcode 8!

Comment: It's not a bug, it's an intentional behaviour to reduce memory consumption. View is not loaded until searchController hasn't become active. Nevertheless `loadViewIfNeeded` suppress this warning I recommend using approach from @JJH answer.

Answer (score 36):

Solved! It was a simple fix. I changed this code

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var resultSearchController = UISearchController()
```

to this:

```
 class ViewController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UISearchBarDelegate {

    var resultSearchController: UISearchController!
```

This fixes the problem.

Comment: I changed it to what you meant. :-) Anyway that's why including the whole source in the question is better, but finding it on your own is best ;-)

Comment: I was having this annoying warning too and, following your answer, I fixed everything. But I don't know why the ! is needed instead of allocating a new UISearchController...would you exaplain me?

Comment: Not sure, I would like an explanation too.

Comment: If I change from var resultSearchController = UISearchController() to var resultSearchController: UISearchController!
I get fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value in noOfRowInSection. I have large number of array, is that creating error? suggest me.

Comment: I figured out, instead of doing delegate and datasource from storyboard, I wrote in the code and the problem was solved.

Comment: +1 on why? Why does declaring the UISearchController as an implicitly unwrapped optional instead of instantiating it silence this warning?

Comment: This change worked for me as well, although I'm not understanding why either. +1 on question above...

Comment: I had the same issue and your answer worked!. But I don't understand why declaring it as an implicit unwrapper optional solves the issue

Comment: It works like a charm! Thanks. It is somehow related to loading the view at an inappropriate time. I think it works because it gets initialised guaranteed NOT before the view itself got loaded, but only after.

Answer (score 20):

Here is the Swift version that worked for me (similar toJJHs answer):

```
deinit{
    if let superView = resultSearchController.view.superview
    {
        superView.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: @alex I put it at the end of the view controller that initializes the resultSearchController.

Comment: You don't really NEED the `if let` since `.removeFromSuperView()` won't do anything if `superview == nil`

Answer (score 11):

```
class SampleClass: UITableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

private let searchController =  UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        searchController.loadViewIfNeeded() // Add this line before accessing searchController
 }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

Hacking together a few solutions I managed to get mine working by adding lines to viewDidLoad *before* fully setting up the UISearchController:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()

    if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
        self.resultSearchController.loadViewIfNeeded()// iOS 9
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        let _ = self.resultSearchController.view          // iOS 8
    }
    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()

    self.tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: I also tried every other solution given here, and none did suppress the warning (although the search controller **does** work at runtime); this did it. Thank you!

Comment: This has helped me as well, but I had to add that line _after_ I initialise UISearchController.  `self.searchController = ({
            let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
            controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
            controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
            
            controller.searchBar.delegate = self
            definesPresentationContext = true
            
            controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
            return controller
        })()`    then   `self.searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()`

Comment: Why do we need to initialize in the block?

Answer (score 7):

In Swift2 I got the same error message due to an obvious bug:

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Oops",
    message:"bla.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", 
     style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Due to a stupid copy error from myself, I had not included the self.presentViewController line. This caused the same error.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift 2.2 version that worked for me

```
deinit {
    self.searchController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

I think it's helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bug. It seems that you have to avoid creating ViewControllers without presenting them. So after `SomeViewController()` or `let variable: SomeViewController` you have to call something like this `self.presentViewController(yourViewController ...etc)`. If you don't do that, you will get this warning when this view controller will be dealocated.

Answer (score 2):

Creating a search controller in `viewDidLoad()` and setting its search bar as the navigation item's title view doesn't create a strong reference to the search controller, which is why it's deallocated.

So instead of doing this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Create search controller
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    // Add search bar to navigation bar
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    // Size search bar
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

You should do this:

```
var searchController: UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Create search controller
    searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    // Add search bar to navigation bar
    navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
    // Size search bar
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Mine is working like this

```
func initSearchControl(){

        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)

        if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
            searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()
        } else {
            let _ = self.searchController.view
        }

        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        definesPresentationContext = true
        tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    }
```

**searchController.loadViewIfNeeded()** solves the problem but you need to call it after initializing the searchController

Answer (score 1):

I used Derek's answer, but had to change it slightly.
The answer that was provided crashed for me because the call to loadViewIfNeeded() happened before the resultSearchController was defined. (My declaration was

```
var resultSearchController: UISearchController!
```

). So I just moved it afterwards and it worked.

If I left out the call entirely, the bug remained, so I'm sure it is an essential part of the answer. I was unable to test it on iOS 8.

Answer (score 1):

It seem the view is lazy loaded, if you allocated the controller and never show it, the view is not loaded. In this case, if the controller is deallocated, you will received this warning. you could show it once, or call it's loadViewIfNeed() method, or use 'let _ = controller.view' to force load the view to avoid this warning.

Comment: on iOS 8, you only can use 'let _ = controller.view'.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late to the party, but here's my solution:

```
var resultSearchController: UISearchController!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.resultSearchController = ({
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        return searchController
    })()

    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.resultSearchController.searchBar
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: How is this different from initializing and setting-up directly; I mean without using the block syntax ?