# iOS - NSInternalInconsistencyException (Table Search)

Tags: ios, objective-c, search

I want to do an iOS App with a Table Search with Objective-C. I have tried this project:

https://github.com/versluis/Table-Search-2015

Now I have tried to set a normal view between the navigation view and the table view. On the normal view is a button which have a push segue to the table view.

When I push this button I come to the table view and the search is still working. But if I use the back button now, the app crashes with the following message:

> 2016-05-19 23:23:29.135 Table Search[2533:63871] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'An instance 0x7f81b95db6e0 of class MainTableViewController was deallocated while key value observers were still registered with it. Current observation info: <NSKeyValueObservationInfo 0x7f81b945c000> (
>   <NSKeyValueObservance 0x7f81b9428720: Observer: 0x7f81b95e9830, Key path: results, Options: <New: YES, Old: NO, Prior: NO> Context: 0x0, Property: 0x7f81b94286f0>
>   )'

Do someone know what is wrong here? Would be nice if you can have a look into this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove observers from your key value observing before MainTableViewController is deallocated. You can do this by overriding dealloc. You should add:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [self removeObserver:self.controller.searchResultsController forKeyPath:@"results"];
}
```

to `MainTableViewController`.

Comment: Ok the app no longer crashes, but now in the console appears the following message: Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UISearchController: 0x7ae59c20>) Is that a problem or can I ignore that?

Comment: That's not related to your question. As it doesn't appear in the demo project I made using your link. Check the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32282401/attempting-to-load-the-view-of-a-view-controller-while-it-is-deallocating-uis