# iOS9 dismissing keyboard causes crash

Tags: crash, keyboard, ios9

When i try to run my app at iOS 9.1 simulator i have a crash

```
Attempting to load the view of a view controller while it is deallocating is not allowed and may result in undefined behavior (<UIInputWindowController: 0x7ff82b036e00>)
```

Crash happens in main function.

Crash happens when i try to dismiss the keyboard with

```
[self.username resignFirstResponder];
```

Also when you `self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false;`

I've read [View appear with modal view animation instead of show (push) animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31006045/view-appear-with-modal-view-animation-instead-of-show-push-animation) with similar issue - but i have only 1 root navigation controller

Any ideas?

iOS 9 only bug

Comment: I've enabled Zombie and here what i've got

[UIInputWindowController parentViewController]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x7f9d29817a00

Answer (score 5):

Issue was with UIViewController category

dealloc method was overridden to clean up notification callbacks.

And it caused a crash on iOS 9. Probably due to the fact [super dealloc] wasn't called (due to ARC restrictions)

Solution - remove dealloc method from category to the UIViewController subclasses